# Puppet access parameters of module through other module

Tags: class, inheritance, puppet, encapsulation, devops

I'm trying to deal with following situation:

```
class profile:mq {
include rabbitmq
}

class rabbitmq (
$user, $pass, $host ) {
...logic...
}
```

I would like to use hiera auto lookup to fill in parameters in rabbitmq through profile::mq class (eg profile::mq:rabbitmq::user: "value", not rabbitmq::user: "value") My guess is to encapsulate rabbitmq but not sure how to do it in puppet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Automated data binding: good plan.

It simply doesn't work the way you propose, however.  The hiera keys by which a given class looks up its parameter values depend only on the class and parameter names.  They are independent of the locus of any and all declarations of that class.  It cannot be otherwise, because multiple declarations of the same class may be evaluated for the same target node, and -- because classes are singletons -- they all declare the same class (instance).

You *may* be able to achieve what you're after by putting the rabbitmq parameter values in a profile-specific level of your Hiera hierarchy.  That doesn't feel quite right to me, but it may serve well enough for your purposes.

Comment: Yeah, I tested this concept yesterday and it seems ok. Main downside is that you have to redefine parameters in rabbitmq module, point them to profile:rabbitmq parameters in class definiftion.

Answer (score 2):

You just have to define:

```
rabbitmq::user: some_user
rabbitmq::pass: some_password
rabbitmq::host: some_host
```

in proper config file in `hiera` hierarchy. The values from `hiera` will be autocratically taken in accont.

Answer (score -2):

You need to declare your params in profile::mq also:

```
class profile::mq($user, $pass, $host) {
  class { 'profile::mq':
    user => $user,
    pass => $pass,
    host => $host
  }
  ...
  ..
}

class rabbitmq($user, $pass, $host) {
  ...
}
```

Here you would instantiate your `rabbitmq` class using `class { rabbitmq: params }` rather than using `include`, that way you can pass your `profile::mq` params to the `rabbitmq` class.

Hope this helps

Comment: Resource-like class declarations are almost always a bad idea.  The few cases where they make sense involve modules' internal classes.  This is a job for Hiera.  As a bonus, use of Hiera means no need to modify third-party modules.

Comment: Hiera would be used to set the parameters for `profile::mq`. @smaj was asking how to set the parameters for `profile::mq` rather than `rabbitmq`. I do agree however that the best practice would be to use hiera for setting the rabbitmq parameters (along with any other parameters in the profile) and just `include`ing the rabbitmq class.

Comment: I repeat: resource-like class declarations are almost always a bad idea.  This case is no exception.  Moreover, on careful re-read of the question, the OP specifically wants to use Hiera-based automated data binding, and that's not what this ansswer describes.